# Find the difference of the shaded areas from two overlapping squares

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

I have a question from a school problem-solving homework sheet.

Here is the diagram of the problem:

[image]

> Question: Two squares, A and B of the side lengths 6 cm and 5 cm respectively, overlap each other partially. Find the difference of the two shaded areas.

[Here is the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW85a.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Can you not take a ruler and measure the sides of the shaded triangle to compute the area?

Comment: @DonThousand This is the only diagram I was given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference of the two shaded areas is just the area difference of the two squares, i.e. $36 - 25 = 11\space \text{cm}^2$. The overlapping area simply cancels out in the difference.

An obvious case is where the smaller square is right inside the larger one.